# Get the error " version `GLIBC_2.14' not found" after installing qt-creator 4.2.1 on RHEL 6.6

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, shared-folders, libraries, qt

I was able to install Qt-5.8.0 on my system (RHEL 6.6). After installation, I also added it to `$PATH`. Now when I type `qmake --version` I get the following output:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.8.0 in /usr/local/Qt-5.8.0/lib
```

When I type `echo $PATH` I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/Qt-5.8.0/bin:/usr/local/Qt-5.8.0/bin:/root/gcc-4.8.2/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin:/root/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin
```

However, qt-creator did not get installed with Qt-5.8.0. So I went to [this link](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) and clicked on the option  "Qt Creator 4.2.1 for Linux 64-bit (93 MB)." This caused the executable `qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.2.1.run` to be downloaded in my Downloads folder.

During the set-up process, I was asked to select the folder to install qt-creator in. So, I created a new folder called `qtcreator` in `/usr/local`. After the setup process was complete, I went to `/usr/local/qtcreator/bin` via the terminal and typed the command `./qtcreator`. It gave the following output:

```
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./qtcreator)
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/libExtensionSystem.so.4)
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/libAggregation.so.4)
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/libUtils.so.4)
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5)
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5)
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Network.so.5)
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
./qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/../Qt/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5)
```

The bin folder contains the following files:

```
qbs            qbs-qmltypes       qbs-setup-toolchains  qtcreator.sh
qbs-config     qbs-setup-android  qt.conf
qbs-config-ui  qbs-setup-qt       qtcreator
```

When I type `./qtcreator.sh` I get the following output:

```
[root@gksrv bin]# ./qtcreator.sh
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator)
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/libExtensionSystem.so.4)
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/libAggregation.so.4)
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/libUtils.so.4)
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5)
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5)
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Network.so.5)
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
/usr/local/qtcreator/bin/qtcreator: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/qtcreator/bin/../lib/qtcreator/../Qt/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5)
```

Are qt-creator and Qt-5.8.0 not compatible with each other? If Qt-5.8.0 is functional why isn't qt-creator working?

Is it absolutely necessary to install `libc.so. 6` for qt-creator? I thought installing Qt-5.8.0 resolved all these dependencies.

Comment: Use the "Qt Online Installer". Then, you need the g++ compiler.

Comment: @AndrewQ Prior to trying all of this, I tried using the online installer but during installation, it gave errors related to gcc_64. I ignored those errors and let the installation process continue. Qt creator (Community) became available but it wasn't opening when I was clicking on it. Due to that, I decided to download Qt from the source.

Comment: @AndrewQ Why would I need the g++ compiler? Wouldn't gcc be sufficient? I have gcc 4.8.2 running on my system.

Comment: Do you have a development workstation (I mean, in a terminal shell are you able to compile and run a simple "helloworld.cpp")?

Comment: g++ is the C++ compiler: all Qt is written in C++. gcc is the C compiler.

Comment: @AndrewQ The CXX compiler I had on my system was 4.4.7. Unfortunately, I over-wrote the libc.so.6 file after building GLIBC_2.14 and that shut-down my system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57317/discussion-between-a-sid-and-andrewq).